# File preview for web

Tags: asp.net, image, preview

We have a document library in our CRM system with ability to upload/download files of any type. I wonder if there is any third-party library, that can help us to build file-preview mechanism. In other words, we need to show small preview image of file (if it supports, of course) on clicking on file.
We need to support at least formats: doc, xls, pdf and all the image formats.

Comment: Enjoy! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should look closer to [GhostScript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/GPL/index.htm). Can't tell right now exactly how to perform such tasks with it, but I think, it's capable to do so. At least you can print with it to PDF and then convert PDF to JPG.

To resize images use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or some other console program