# How to show word document in browser in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, ms-word

I have successfully embedded microsoft word document in JFrame . Now I want to convert it in web based .

What I have done is as follows :

[image]

Now I want to open microsoft word document in browser by jsp code . I have researched a lot in internet and found the following code :

```
WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/DocReader"})
public class DocReader extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet DocReader</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet DocReader at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
   /* @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } */

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, res);
        ServletOutputStream  out           = 
        res.getOutputStream ();
//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Set the output data's mime type
//---------------------------------------------------------------
    res.setContentType( "application/pdf" );  // MIME type for pdf doc
//---------------------------------------------------------------
// create an input stream from fileURL
//---------------------------------------------------------------
    String fileURL = 
        "http://www.adobe.com/aboutadobe/careeropp/pdfs/adobeapp.pdf";
//------------------------------------------------------------
// Content-disposition header - don't open in browser and
// set the "Save As..." filename.
// *There is reportedly a bug in IE4.0 which  ignores this...
//------------------------------------------------------------
    res.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                  "attachment; filename=" +
                  "Example.pdf" );
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// PROXY_HOST and PROXY_PORT should be your proxy host and port
// that will let you go through the firewall without authentication.
// Otherwise set the system properties and use URLConnection.getInputStream().
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
    BufferedInputStream  bis = null; 
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    String PROXY_HOST="";
    String PROXY_PORT="";
    try {
        URL url = new URL( "http", PROXY_HOST, 
                           Integer.parseInt(PROXY_PORT), fileURL  );
        // Use Buffered Stream for reading/writing.
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
        byte[] buff = new byte[2048];
        int bytesRead;
        // Simple read/write loop.
        while(-1 != (bytesRead = bis.read(buff, 0, buff.length))) {
            bos.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } catch(final MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println ( "MalformedURLException." );
        throw e;
    } catch(final IOException e) {
        System.out.println ( "IOException." );
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (bis != null)
            bis.close();
        if (bos != null)
            bos.close();
    }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

But it does not embed the word document in browser . How can I show microsoft word document in browser > Please help me .

Comment: pdf file is not a a word file

Comment: I think the embedding procedure of pdf and word is same .

Comment: Take a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-to-render-word-documentdoc-docx-in-browser-using-javascript