# React File Preview (FIREBASE)

Tags: file, reactjs, firebase, preview, firebase-storage

I currently have files stored in Firebase Storage. I want to be able to generate a file preview for each file in real time (mapping).

For example, a PDF files will show the first page as an image, a .docx will be the first page of the document, a pptx will be the first slide, an unknown document will be a default document symbol.

Anyone know any good services for easy integration into React ES6?

Comment: Enjoy! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript