# how to view the docx and pptx file in website (localhost)

Tags: php, html

how to  view the docx and pptx file when a link is clicked it should open in a new tab and viewed it in offline using HTML5 or php or js or anything else

Comment: can you convert those files into PDF??? If yes then use iframe

Comment: And another easy way is, you can make those files downloadable by user. Where user can download and open

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-to-render-word-documentdoc-docx-in-browser-using-javascript.

Comment: how can i convert those files into pdf??... Webdev

Comment: and i need to view that docx and pptx file from local drive and it will be uploaded by the admin dynamically..........