# open a word document in internet explorer after a link click

Tags: javascript, html, windows, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

I want to open word document internet explorer , after clicking a link browser in browser it should open child browser window in that i want to show clicked word document , after the edit i want to show a "save" button in that document.   by default it has to open in browser window why it is not opening. now after clicking  a link child window is appearing , document  is not opening in child window, it is opening office documents.

```
    <body onload="startWord('https://xxxxx/documentEdit/remoteDocument.docx')">
<a href="javascript:startWord('https://xxxxxxx/documentEdit/remoteDocument.docx')">open file</a>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function startWord(strFile)
{
var myApp = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
if (myApp != null)
{
myApp.Visible = true;
//myApp.Documents.Open(strFile);
 windowObjectReference = window.open(strFile,
   "PromoteFirefoxWindowName", "resizable,scrollbars,status");
}
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Look in the console.

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript

Comment: DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337