# How to view office files into web page like google drive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

My project is based on Node.js (backed end) and AngularJs (front end), so I want to open Office files (.doc .ppt and so on) into my web page. My files are stored into Amazon s3 server. I want to to open these files into my web page.

So I need similar kind of functionality like google drive have for viewing the files.

Any Idea?

Comment: do you require only to view the file?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to view only, you can use Google Documents' Viewer via an `<iframe>` or Microsoft Office 365 viewer via an `<iframe>`.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://remote.url.tld/path/to/document.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

or

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=http://remote.url.tld/path/to/document.doc' width='1366px' height='623px' frameborder='0'>This is an embedded <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com'>Microsoft Office</a> document, powered by <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com/webapps'>Office Online</a>.</iframe>
```

Solution obtained from [How do I render a Word document (.doc, .docx) in the browser using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript)

Comment: Is there any way to open the docs in html and css format? like pdf.js for pdf file

Comment: I can't think of a library for the Microsoft proprietary formats. There are tools like http://viewerjs.org/ and http://webodf.org/ . But the y only support Open Document Format.