# Sharepoint Rest API to read a .docx file in the document library from nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, sharepoint

I need to read a file in sharepoint document library from node js and store it in a variable. I can read .txt files using sharepoint rest api. sharepoint site/_api/web/ GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents/s_C_locations.txt')/$value.But when I try to read .docx file it returns something as below:

```
PK!����]�[Content_Types].xml ��(����N�0E�H�C�-j\@B5e�c  H���LZ�_�L��=�@��"Ҳ���s��鋳�$4�b?����B܍.{�"CR�T6x(�P�ww�y�8�c!�D�DJ�Sp
���J�Sįi"�ҏj��?�:xO=�5�pp��Y�.^��I�";{�X{B�h�VĤ�ɗ_\z�9G6{pj"�1��K"L�8W#6�cj��P�^�\�dJ
���z)��_���� Xml/item2.xmlPK-!�H���`customXml/itemProps1.xmlPK-!\�'"�(�acustomXml/_rels/item2.xml.relsPK-!���.j�ccustomXml/item3.xmlPK-!�^����<ecustomXml/itemProps3.xmlPK-!�U�j�OfdocProps/custom.xmlPK-!{���(�hcustomXml/_rels/item3.xml.relsPK��
```

Please help me to resolve it

Comment: this is text representation of a binary file (.zip), everything is fine. What you need is proper viewer, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27958186/1498401

Comment: Hi @tinamou,I don't need to render it in a browser.I want to read a file  content in node js and store it in a variable.

Comment: how you understand file content? Word documents (.docx) have fonts, paragraphs, tables, objects, images etc. not only text like .txt files

Comment: Yes .docx file contain all those you mentioned. Is there any way to read those files,because in my project I need to read the content and do analysis on that.And another one is if the .docx present in the local(inside my project folder) I can read it using the textract module in node js. But the use case is to read from sharepoint document library

Comment: there are `textract` methods to extract from buffer or url

Comment: Can you provide a small code using textract to read a file from sharepoint document library

Answer (score 1):

Using `encoding: null` is a key here.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/koltyakov/sppull/blob/master/src/api/index.ts#L242) how to download a file from SharePoint correctly with Node.js and REST API.

You can simplify a task and grab ready to use libraries like sppull or [sp-download](https://github.com/koltyakov/sp-download) for example.

Cheers,
Andrew

Comment: Thanks for your relpy Andrew. I used encoding:null .It returns as <Buffer 50 4b 03 04 14 00 06 00 08 00 00 00 21 00 f4 9a bf e5 9f 01 00 00 5d 07 00 00 13 00 cf 01 5b 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 5f 54 79 70 65 73 5d 2e 78 6d 6c 20 ... >...sppull is used to download all the documents in the document library.I need to download only one file

Comment: Andrew, I am using Postman then RestSharp. Encoding:null as a header does nothing. your JS code passes it not in a header. what should the accept and Content-type be in the headers? Thanks