# Word upload and preview - Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, paperclip

Rails 4.2.5 and ruby 2.3.3p222

I am using Paperclip to upload files, if I upload pdf's the display works fine but I cant find a way to display word files correctly in the browser.

Model:

```
has_attached_file :document
validates_attachment :document, :content_type => { :content_type => %w(application/pdf application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document) }
```

In my form:

```
<%= f.input :document, as: :file %>
```

In my show:

```
<iframe src="<%= @article.document.url %>" style="height:800px;width:100%"></iframe>
```

Again, if its a pdf it shows perfectly, although if its a word file it just downloads the file instantly as soon as I load the page.

I think its the  that I am using in the Show page but cant find any solution when searching on google. 
Anyone tried to do this or has any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can render a *.doc file in the browser. There is an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27958186/5239030).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, looks like they used the Google Docs Viewer to show the doc, what is all I need, I tried but gives an error saying that the file cant be found. I believe that we would need to send this to google docs online before or something?
This is what I have tried:
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<%= @article.document.url %>&embedded=true" style="height:800px;width:100%"></iframe>