# Document(doc,docx,pdf) preview in web page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I tried different methods like iframe ,object to view/show the document on web page as a preview.Iframme with google doc only worked for publicaly available document.How can I display/preview document stored on my localhost folder.

Comment: iframe should work. Not sure what you mean that it only works for "publicly available documents", it seems like it should be obvious that you can only iframe documents that you have access to

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript

Comment: Tried that but the host should be exposed to outside.any other options other than using google doc or microsoft view?

Answer (score 3):

You can use iframe tag of html as following:

```js
 const YOUR_URL = https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx;
 
 <iframe
   className="doc"
   src={`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${YOUR_URL}&embedded=true`}
 />
```