# Docx preview with Google & Microsoft

Tags: security, ms-word, ms-office, docx, privacy

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript), there is a proposed solution to preview the Word files with Google and Microsoft viewers. Both solution work pretty well, but there is a restriction for this project that the documents can't leave Europe.

I am wondering the following questions:

1. Does Google/Microsoft store the files on their server after they have downloaded it? I see that the file download does not happen in the browser, but in both cases it is served as image.
2. If the request is from Europe, is the document processed on European servers? And if no, is it possible to somehow influence it?

Here are the examples for the convenience:

https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://omextemplates.content.office.net/support/templates/en-us/tf10002117.docx

https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://omextemplates.content.office.net/support/templates/en-us/tf10002117.docx

PS: in case it is relevant, the document itself is stored in Google Storage European region.

Comment: I think there is no way of knowing for sure, you better ask Google/Microsoft these questions directly, but you will never know if it is accurate and it might evolve.

Comment: Yes, I am afraid so. @ Google, @ Micorsoft, please respond