# How to store and search Resume's (CV's) on Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, static, django-forms

In Django, I have a process where a user can upload a resume, which gets stored on my fileserver.

For each resume uploaded a member of staff creates a Database record (fills in a form which is saved  to postgresql)

My dilema is that the actual resume is either a microsoft word document or a pdf document. I want staff upon calling up the candidate profile which has a list of resumes that the candidate has sent in, I want staff to be able to open the resume and have a read of the docx or pdf file which the web page has a path to.

How should i go about doing this.
The other thing is, in phase 2, i want staff to be able to search the resumes for certain skill sets, so i am not sure if the staff should:
make a summary of skills and store under the candidate record for searching later
or maybe the staff should convert all pdf and docx documents to text strings and store in a field under the candidate record.
or maybe i should keep the files as pdf and docx and somehow (i dont know how) i should create some mechanism to search the actual docx and pdf files for required skills.

I am a bit confused on the matter, and would like to know which would be the best approach for my above problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well displaying resume (PDF) is easy, simply use a link to the file. For word document you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27958186/7852595).

Now for your other problem, searching for specific skills, what you can do is use a skills table in your database which must be filled when your users are submitting their resume. You can then apply your filter.

Comment: Thanks Ubaid, I am new to all this and was a bit adventurous with my first project, having to learn django and python, and basically how to approach a task. It is a lot harder than i first thought.