# How I can save *.docx file in sql server and show it

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, web

I have some problem. I'am try to save *.docx fail in sql server and show it in web-site. I can save my file in sql server using this code

```
 Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(varFilePath);
        String file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        using (SqlConnection sql_connetion = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database_connection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sql_connetion.Open();
            using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO use_of_rule (ID, taj) Values('3', @File)", sql_connetion))
            {
                sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@File", bytes);
                sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return "ok";
            }
        }
```

I want to display the content of the file in the web browser. How I can do it?

Comment: Sorry faile=file

Comment: You are using WAS? (Office Web App Server)

Comment: As you are saving it I guess its byte[] which is pretty much useless for you since you need the text.... In order to get the text you need to use "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" to open the file and read the contents. if you save your files in SQL as byte[] you will have to do some extra work when you are requesting to read the file and write the byte[] into a file before opening it...

Comment: "_and_ _show_ _it_", as in "Have a link a user can click and open the file" or "See the content of the file in the browser"?

Comment: What are you offer in this situation

Comment: See the content of the file in the browser

Comment: [How do I render a Word document (.doc, .docx) in the browser using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I render a Word document (.doc, .docx) in the browser using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Word from WAS (Office Web App Server), you need to do something like this:

1 Create a simple web site to read the data from sql.
You could create a Generic Handler (ashx) in ASP.Net site, providing the plain word file data as response. Dont forget to set the content type as "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document".

2 Use url encoding to encode the link created in step 1, including all parameters you may want to pass into it.

3 To launch Word, you need to nav it to http(s)://your.was.server.name/op/view.aspx?src=paste.encoded.url.here

Comment: have your example