# View office app live Document viewer not working

Tags: php, document, viewer

I am using this view.officeapplive document viewer and have created it with my document

http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=https://206.128.155.68/bfs-dev/uploads/order_type_doc/orderid-17471/Word.docx

But its not working. Can anyone help me with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should encode your URL. Also, you can try google link to view your document like below

[Google Document Viewer](https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https%3A%2F%2F206.128.155.68%2Fbfs-dev%2Fuploads%2Forder_type_doc%2Forderid-17471%2FWord.docx)

Try this google link

```
https://docs.google.com/gview?url=<Paste your encoded URL HERE>
```

Comment: Yes I have also tried with encoded url.
https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=https%3A%2F%2F206.128.155.68%2Fbfs-dev%2Fuploads%2Forder_type_doc%2Forderid-17471%2FWord.docx
But its also happening with the same error output.
Actually client is not very fond of gview scenario thats why searching to find any other which will work with pdf,docx as well as xlsx and pptx

Comment: Please go through this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2013/04/10/office-web-viewer-view-office-documents-in-a-browser/) to know more. Also, make sure that your document is publicly accessible or not. You can go through this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript) might be it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you havn't configured your site correctly. When I tried opening the file link in browser, It is showing your [ssl](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority) certificate is not valid

Answer (score 0):

it is because the ip is not supported by ms viewer, you may need a domain name for this case. I also got this issue.