# Is there any way to read word template in angular 6 and make changes of some tages and download in pdf file

Tags: javascript, angular

This is word templates and parameters which I want to replace:

[image]

Comment: Have a look here for some interesting ideas how to manage the embed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27958186/3623608

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need is very specific and I am sure there is nothing out of the box in Angular.
However there are libraries using which you can create your own Angular Service.
**One such library is** https://webodf.org/
This api is in javascript, you can find the functionalities you need in the this api and create a Angular Service wrapper on top of it.