# Html anchor link file view in new tab of browser

Tags: html, css, anchor

> Hi I want to view 4 types of files ( doc,docx,pdf,txt ) in the web browser's next tab, I am using file://// to solve this but this only download the file not viewing in a browser.

```
<a href="http://localhost/career/resume_application/2019-04- 19T134944.012378dummy.doc" target="_blank" title="View Resume"><img src="../img/view.svg" height="20px"></a>
```

> I want to view this file () in next tab when I click on an anchor tag, is it possible or other information help me if I do that in another way

Comment: Already answered on stackflow, you can not render doc files on browser

Comment: Here is alternative solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript