# Displayed a document word , xlsx and pptx in <embed></embed> as file pdf

Tags: html, symfony

i'm trying to create frame in my page web where the document can be displayed as a file pfd it work properly using

```
<embed src="/pdf/../" type='application/pdf' ></embed>
```

Have you any idea about how to make a file .docx , .pptx and .xlsx be displayed in browser such as a pdf .. and the file is saved on my local 
i trying to use this one:

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=[path to the file]' ></iframe>
```

but unfortunately this one need googleDrive or one drive.

I need one that can be using for files saved in my local.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I render a Word document (.doc, .docx) in the browser using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but i think with this solution you need to save files in googleDrive or i need a solution for files that are saved in my local ... or i false ?

Comment: The files need to be hosted on an external server somewhere

Comment: humm, i'm looking for a solution that files only saved in my local...

Comment: That's not possible. The file needs to exist on an external server in order for it to be accessible via the web.