# React: how to display most of documents on browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, libreoffice, file-conversion

**Background:**

Here is my use case, an app that user uploads documents and will be showed as a link allow him to click. Once it is clicked, it will popup and display the actual content. e.g. like a document viewer that you can scroll to see content.

I have **around 100 file** types (*no video type*) need to display. Whether it is displayed as original document, html or image. The user doesn't really care, **as long as the content can be viewed**.

**Approach 1:**

[Native browsers are not able to support all the document types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript)

[React file viewer support some of file types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-viewer), but not most of them.

- Images: png, jpeg, gif, bmp, including 360-degree images
- pdf
- csv
- xslx
- docx
- Video: mp4, webm
- Audio: mp3

**Question 1:**

Is there any paid file viewer that support most of the file types?

**Approach 2:**

I upload files to micro-service, then it converts the file to an image, react can display it easily.

1. upload file to a micro service.
2. convert the file to an image and display in react
3. e.g. https://medium.com/batary/file-conversion-microservice-cba0e9321151

Example supported documents

```
txt rtf doc docx ppt pptx xls xlsx csv html pdf 
latex bib bmp svg eps tiff png jpg gif apng 
mp3 ogg mp4 avi webm mkv mov flv
```

It is better, but the supported doc type need to increase. It uses **LibreOffice** as a process to convert files

**Question 2**

Is it able to support more document types?