# how to display word document in my html page

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, embed, doc

i want to display the word document in my html page , i am using iframe , embed tags to displaying the 
  document, it works for pdf but not doc files, can any one please help me regarding this. it is possible or not?

```html
 <iframe src="wd-spectools-word-sample-04.doc" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"> 
  </iframe>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I render a Word document (.doc, .docx) in the browser using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<iframe style="width:600px; height:500px;" src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://writing.engr.psu.edu/workbooks/formal_report_template.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```