# signed url generated by gcp not working with google doc viewer in iframe

Tags: iframe, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url, google-document-viewer

signed url of cloud storage object in gcp not working with google or microsoft doc viewer in iframe .

```
<iframe id="iframe-tag" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.googleapis.com%2Futkarsh-video-bucket%2Fsample.docx%3FExpires%3D1579189477%26amp%3BGoogleAccessId%3Dvideo-streaming-258309%2540appspot.gserviceaccount.com%26amp%3BSignature%3Dlr4j6y7768p3Z50ttJu%252Bi3bZ1FmaesQsMySHNNO%252FA7bHJObLloFiU2VtOYaDjxXwfuvO5x1Xmd2hD1A8ZTZMpP9WGDM1Z7W1m4oWqI%252FFJHspNhYm00Hr9rdlBORpGWjGYtogfDPIbXs2v4tHDyO%252BluEVQJwZN4b0mW1bKc3q5FYbFi3cQTTf7IXE5trbymiln4coakd9R%252FIIv2Ii9a%252F%252FdtLx0KB6N5u3j1oGEoj6t%252FfONLQ7bHQ5xEDY%252F7IWPPNkErIV%252BiKPgYqNVeQ04dqUC9Z0Mzcm1LpVK%252FsUX1TPSH2Ear8vIcX9fh15znCLvOg3OewYuR5PLPmsCXOueh4cOg%253D%253D&amp;embedded=true"></iframe>
```

it can be downloaded through browser.

Comment: How did you create the signed URL?

Comment: V4 signed URLs api

Comment: Would you mind sharing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code used (without sharing any sensitive information) to create the signed URLs? Also specify which programming language you are using. I noticed that the URL you are giving replaces all the `/` and `:` signs with their respective [URL encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP), while on other [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript) I don't see they are replaced.

Comment: Hello @UtkarshShende: Did you find a solution. I am generating the URL via `getDownloadURL` method of google storage. However, docs viewer is throwing cannot reach error. Thanks

Comment: Hello @RmR, signed URL generated needs to be converted into base64 format, for the browser to understand it properly.

Comment: Thanks @UtkarshShende. Will give it a try