# Display the word document from wwwroot folder instead of downloading: ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to show the document located inside **wwwroot** folder in my .NET MVC Core application folder in an iframe.

Scenario:

I have a list of document on my Razor page: MyRazor.cshtml and there is a button for each list. When I click that button it takes me to the details of individual document using its Id.

When the page loads, the document gets downloaded instead of showing in iframe src.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult GetArticles(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            Articles getArticles = _articleRepository.GetArticles(id);
            return View(getArticles);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
<div class="card">
    <iframe id="documentViewer" src="~/docs/@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.WordDocumentFile)" width="100%" height="700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

which is undesirable. I just want the show that document inside my iframe.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because doc files are not known by the web browsers, you need to transform them to HTML or PDF.**

The best way is to store the `PDF` file in the corresponding folder, and then read the PDF file directly to display the content of the document, rather than download the file.

You can also refer to this:[How do I render a Word document (.doc, .docx) in the browser using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Yongqing Yu's answer sort of stated it, but I just want to elaborate that if the PDF is in your `wwwroot` folder, all you need to do is

`<iframe src="~/docs/mypdf.pdf">`

On a view, `~/` is already relative to the static files stored in `wwwroot`