# Display Word documents online

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, ms-word

I need to display some word documents on our React Website.
I'm working on Local network, so I have no internet connection.
Already tried react-file-viewer & react-doc-viewer, but it looks pretty broken.
Any way of doing it is exist?

Comment: I think this question already exists. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot find my answer there.
I'm using Local network, which means I have no internet connection, so the solutions provided there not working for me.