# Reading content of a .docx file in browser

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ms-word, frontend

I want to read the content of a .docx file in client side using javascript. I use vue.js but I'm looking for any solutions.

The goal is to edit it's content.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I render a Word document (.doc, .docx) in the browser using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript)

Comment: Any reason to not use Word Online to edit the content? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information needed in your question here.