# Office Web Apps preview Word document Base64

Tags: javascript, base64

Goal: **Preview** .docx **Base64 (or blob)** in Browser (javascript / html) in a simple <object .. /> container

This does preview a file, but my document paths are not public (I only funnel base64 or blobs to the end-browser)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27958186/2743486

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=http://remote.url.tld/path/to/document.doc' width='1366px' height='623px' frameborder='0'>This is an embedded <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com'>Microsoft Office</a> document, powered by <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com/webapps'>Office Online</a>.</iframe>
```

This is above file as base64 ... How do I use the "office viewer" to display it?
https://jsfiddle.net/5cve3kLm/

Comment: No. I did not want to invest more time into this sorry. (If I did have time I would look at client-side conversion from .docx to .pdf, or just jpeg, with then can be displayed as a preview)