# how to open microsoft office 365 word file in iframe in edit mode

Tags: html, iframe, ms-word, office365

based on [Embed a Word document in your blog](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/embed-a-word-document-in-your-blog-0faa0253-2751-44bf-8486-ea7837fe7db1), I know how can I embed a word document in an iframe in **read-only mode**. but I'm looking for a solution to open it in edit mode.

is there any way to open an office 365-word document in edit mode on an external website?

I tried to just put a sample document in an iframe but had no sucess.

update:

also I found this thread https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/embed-o365-edit-link-in-an-iframe/ce46bc84-755a-4cf3-98ca-776ba143b671?page=2 but looks like it's too old and maybe since 2016 some method and solution has been developed to embed edit mode.

```html
<iframe src="https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?resid=5D099B6B963F20FB!118&ithint=file%2cdocx&wdOrigin=OFFICECOM-WEB.START.MRU">
</iframe>
```

console error:

> Refused to display 'https://onedrive.live.com/' in a frame because it
> set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Comment: You tried to copy the url to ifarme?

Comment: @amiad yes, I copy the url to iframe

Comment: The url of edit mode? What happen?

Comment: @amiad parent restriction. I don't remember the exact message but it was about using in another url is restricted. 
you can try it.

Comment: `I don't remember the exact message`...well it might be important don't you think? Can you go back and check? P.S. how is this relevant to PHP?

Comment: @ADyson because I'm not looking specifically to resolve that issue. I'm looking for a solution, it could be any solution.

php was miss-added- I remved it. thanks to let me know.

Comment: Well an iframe is a potential solution. Possibly the error is resolvable, if you tell us what it is. We should at least rule it out.

Comment: @ADyson I updated the question with a sample

Comment: Have you tried this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/embed-files-directly-into-your-website-or-blog-ed07dd52-8bdb-431d-96a5-cbe8a80b7418 ?

Comment: @ADyson as I mentioned in the question, I want edit mode  not view mode only

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear from that documentation that it creates a read only link. Will keep thinking

Comment: @ADyson thanks a lot. I'm really stuck on this

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is, that the browser is sending an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header. This option prevents the browser from displaying iFrames that are not hosted on the same domain as the parent page.

See: [Mozilla Developer Network - The X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

A solution will be to load it as an embed so Mircosoft will not redirect you a 1000 times. Mabye look at this:
[How do I render a Word document (.doc, .docx) in the browser using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want stay stucked in this trouble, have one way to resolve this, but this is very complexy/dificultly, following these steps:

1. You need an Office 365 account and provide a SharePoint site were you'll add all files that you want to open in edit mode (put all files into a Document Library list);
2. Following this tutorial to bypassing this SharePoint site (that you added documents to be opened in edit mode) into HTML Iframe: [How To Bypass Cross Domain Issues To Display SharePoint Online Pages Within Iframe From An External Domain](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-bypass-cross-domain-issues-to-display-sharepoint-online-pages-within-iframe-from-an-external-domain/)
3. Into SharePoint site, develop a Web Part that allow users to open files in edit mode, following this tutorial: [Office Web Apps (Word, Excel, PowerPoint) Link To "Open File In Iframe"](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/office-web-apps-word-excel-powerpoint-link-to-open-file-in-iframe/);

I believe in this way like the best alternative to resolves this challenge.

Comment: Hi Antonio, thank you for your attention.
looks like the suggested solution needs  ASP langague. our server is PHP base and there is no chance to write code in ASP.

Comment: Hi @Yuseferi, you do not need to host an asp/asp.net site; the idea is, you make a Office365 assignment (everything in Office365 is based in cloud) and into your site hosts you'll consume this services by your site iframe. About SharePoint Online, learn more at these articles: [Introduction to SharePoint in Microsoft 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/introduction) and [What is SharePoint Online?](https://www.office365brasil.com.br/sharepoint-online.htm)

Comment: Could you provide a  sample if it's just an iframe?