# Preview generated docx before downloading

Tags: javascript, ms-word, preview

I use the code in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7fwuch3/)
To generate and download docx file using some libraries. I want to preview the generated docx in an Iframe before downloading it. I tried with the var `out`
But not get it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript

Comment: I tried that but not work

Comment: It's a generated docx