# preview generated doc from html

Tags: javascript

I use this function to generate ms word file from html content. Is there a way to preview the generated word file in the webpage

```
function Export2Word(element, filename = ''){
    var preHtml = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></head><body>";
    var postHtml = "</body></html>";
    var html = preHtml+document.getElementById(element).innerHTML+postHtml;

    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
        type: 'application/msword'
    });
    
    // Specify link url
    var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
    
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.doc':'document.doc';
    
    // Create download link element
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ){
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = url;
        
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
    
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

I tried Google doc prevew and office but it doesn't open

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that when all you have is a dataURL.

Comment: Your answer is maybe already in this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript

Comment: Can we convert dataURL to file ?