# ASP.NET MVC : how to open any file in a new tab?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I used the following code which is working for a PDF in chrome browser

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "GetReport", new { controller = "Storage" }, new { target = "_blank" })
```

Here is my code inside controller

```
public FileResult GetReport()
{
    string ReportURL = @"C:\Tools\HazMat\HazMat\Uploads\IAC HILL TOP CAMPING LIST OF FREE ADVENTURE ACTIVITIES..pdf";
    byte[] FileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ReportURL);

    return File(FileBytes, "application/pdf");
}
```

When I gave a path related to `docx` file here it is downloading instead of opening the document so how can I open any kind of file in to a new tab

Comment: `byte[] FileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ReportURL);` <-- Doing this is **very** inefficient - you should pass an async-capable `FileStream` to `FileResult` so it can efficiently _stream_ the response to the client asynchronously, but your code buffers the entire file into memory... and uses the (_old-hat_) synchronous (i.e. thread-blocking) `File.ReadAllBytes` method...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes you think browsers will display `.docx` files just like how they show PDFs? (I haven't seen a browser open Office files in-place since Office 2003 running with IE6 or maybe Office 2007 with IE7  - since then this kind of browser-based OLE is _dead_).

Answer (score 0):

If you set **Disposition** in the header it will open your file in the browser.

```
public FileResult GetReport()
{
 string ReportURL = @"C:\Tools\HazMat\HazMat\Uploads\IAC HILL TOP CAMPING LIST OF FREE ADVENTURE ACTIVITIES..pdf";
 byte[] FileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ReportURL);

 //Add this key
 Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"inline; filename={file.FileName}.pdf");
 return File(FileBytes, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: Will this work from word documents too?

Comment: @Developer Browsers don't have any built-in feature to render Word docs.

Comment: @Developer, for your Word files and other formatted files which are not supported by browser you have to use tools like (viewerjs), check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript