# How to serve files of different format from AWS s3 to HTML page

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, iframe

How can i serve files of different format(pdf,xlsx,doc) stored in a AWS s3 bucket to a HTML page with iframe. I am able to get pdf file but other type of files just downloads in the browser instead of displaying.

To render the pdf file, I am first converting the content to a blob and passing it to src of iframe as below,

```
<div>
   <iframe className="w-screen h-screen" src={file} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible without providing a viewer for these filetypes.

The reason the pdf file is displayed, is because most modern web browsers contain a pdf viewer by default.

Take a look at this similar question: [How do I render a Word document (.doc, .docx) in the browser using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript)