# Embed Word document on Intranet page

Tags: html, ms-word, embed

I need to embed a word document on a page on our Intranet. Because we're on an internal Intranet, I am unable to use the Office or Google viewers. I have the following code to display the document, but it just downloads the file. Any help is appreciated.

```
?><iframe src="<?php echo $fulllink; ?>" width="1000" height="1000"></iframe><?php
```

Comment: This is not a PHP issue. Possible solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, most of those use the Office or Google viewer, which I can't use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I render a Word document (.doc, .docx) in the browser using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript)