# How to view word and excel documents in angular

Tags: angular, iframe, ngx-doc-viewer

I am working on a project to display word and excel file in webpage. Currently using ngx doc viewer. The file url is coming in api response but with ngx doc viewer I am either getting no preview available or file is getting downloaded.
< ngx doc viewer [url]=“fileurl” viewer=“Google>
For above syntax I get no preview available.
If I replace google with pdf I get file downloaded.
I also tried I frame but no luck.
Any alternative or suggestions Is welcome.

I tried ngx doc viewer and file getting either downloaded or no preview available

Comment: This has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript