# React: File preview for PFD/docx/xls/jpg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

How do I show a file preview for PFD/docx/xls/jpg files using React.js or web?

This question has been asked before but no one has answered, so I'm trying to get more attention:
[React File Preview (FIREBASE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500962/react-file-preview-firebase)

[File preview for web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734037/file-preview-for-web)

Someone please answer.

Comment: This one liner worked great: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript